# Class constructor type

Tags: typescript

I want to require one or the other type of constructor in my class:

```
const instance: MyClass = new MyClass({ digit: 5 });
```

... or ...

```
const instance: MyClass = new MyClass({ letter: 'x' });
```

It cannot be two at the same time, or some other objects.

At the moment I have this:

```
interface MyClassConstructor {
    digit?;
    letter?;
}
interface MyClassDigit extends MyClassConstructor {
    digit: number;
}
interface MyClassLetter extends MyClassConstructor {
    letter: string;
}

class MyClass {
    constructor(obj: MyClassDigit | MyClassLetter) {
        if (obj.digit) {
            // ...
        } else if (obj.letter) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I dont think its the proper way of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the `constructor`:

```
interface WithDigit {
    digit: number
}

interface WithLetter {
    letter: string
}

class MyClass {
    constructor(options: WithDigit);
    constructor(options: WithLetter);
    constructor(options: WithLetter | WithDigit) {
        if ('digit' in options) {
            /* */
        }

        if ('letter' in options) {
            /* */
        }
    }
}
```

This will make sure only one is accepted.

```
new MyClass({ digit: 0 });              // OK
new MyClass({ letter: 'a' });           // OK
new MyClass({ digit: 0, letter: 'a' }); // Error
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not change much about your solution. I would not have the base interface with both properties. I would just use a union and an `in` type guard:

```
interface MyClassDigit {
    digit: number;
}
interface MyClassLetter {
    letter: string;
}

class MyClass {
    constructor(obj: MyClassDigit | MyClassLetter) {
        if ('digit' in obj) {
            // obj is MyClassDigit
        } else {
            // obj is MyClassLetter
        }
    }
}
```

If you have more parameters and want to require just one member, you can generate the type automatically using conditional types:

```
interface MyParams {
    digit?: number;
    letter?: string;
}
type RequireOne<T> = (keyof T) extends infer K ?
    K extends keyof T ?
    Required<Pick<T, K>> : never : never

class MyClass {
    constructor(obj: RequireOne<MyParams>) {
        if ('digit' in obj) {
            // obj has digit
        } else {
            // obj has letter 
        }
    }
}
```